# When should I use comm over diff?

Tags: diff, comm

It seems diff can do anything comm can do? When should I use comm only but not diff excepting the difference in result format? I guess comm is faster?

Comment: You are incorrect. Read `man diff comm` and you should see that their functions don't overlap very much.

Comment: As already pointed out, comm and diff are two very different programs. Check the man pages for the different usages.